# Vimeo unity SDK: Is there a way to use a team member's authorization to gain access to main user's videos?

Tags: unity-game-engine, sdk, authorization, vimeo

We're working on a unity project involving using unity vimeo sdk (https://github.com/vimeo/vimeo-unity-sdk#setting-up). The client who we are working for has a vimeo account with the videos that needs to be displayed in the application. The client has created a vimeo account for us and added it to team members of their main account, with administrator rights. The client has a vimeo pro account.

After clicking the get token-button and logging in with the team member account created for us and adding the received api token, we now have access to only videos uploaded to that team member's account, but not to the videos that are on the main account. Using an url of the main user's video gives an error in unity:

"[VimeoPlayer] You do not have permission to access to this video. You must be a Vimeo Pro or Business customer and use videos from your own account. https://vimeo.com/upgrade".

We can switch the team account to the client's account in a web browser and modify the videos according to given usage rights, but we can't use the videos of the main user. We also tried logging in to the team account on a browser, switching team role to the client's account, and then doing the authentication through unity, but this didn't give us access to the videos in unity.

We would like to know if there's a way to use the main user's videos on team member account WITHOUT logging in and authorizing with the main account. The only solution we came out is that if the client doesn't want to share the main account's user credentials, they will have to use Unity to log in to vimeo in their end, then send us the token. According to our tests that approach will work, but it's a bit of a hassle.

Comment: Do you have a link to the support request?

Comment: No worries, I see they use Stackoverflow for support requests :)

Answer (score 1):

A few things:

1. Contact Vimeo while logged into your paid account to [request support](https://vimeo.com/help/contact).
2. Vimeo's team membership system doesn't extend to the API since the API can be used outside of that team system. The API can only be used to interact with your own Vimeo account, and you can only read public metadata for other user accounts.

Comment: It would still be very useful to know the technical requirement for this issue.

Comment: The Vimeo link provided, Vimeo officially indicates to request support via StackOverflow! So the issue was not the original poster, but Vimeo tech staff waiting to use Stackoverflow as a product support channel.

Answer (score 0):

I just ask the original account holder who purchased the Pro subscription to provide the access token by asking them to visit:
https://authy.vimeo.com/auth/vimeo/unity?scope=public%20private%20video_files

He then provided the token, which then worked as expected in Unity.

Vimeo docs do not indicate this requirement.